# Does anyone know any videos on how to check wheat grains from Bugs

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization, bugs, yoreh-deah

BH

Any videos on how to check wheat Grains from bugs before making flour and the type of bugs that could possibly come into wheat grains?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XFqvegy8q4Q